# Facebook / Graph API - How do I find the app id of another application (that I don't own)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to find the developer contact info / app profile page for an application I don't own. How do I find the app id for a particular namespace (eg. http://apps.facebook.com/some_app_namespace)? The namespace directs to a 404, so the owner hasn't setup a canvas url or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be assigned to a deactivated or disabled app, locked for copyright or trademark reasons, too long / too short, etc. 
Short answer is there's probably no way to get it.

If you already have a trademark which covers the name you want to use, you could contact Facebook and ask for it to be assigned to you, i'm not 100% sure in which circumstances such a request would succeed, but i recommend here as a starting point: https://www.facebook.com/legal/copyright.php